# Dynamically add key val pairs to google app script json

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

Here is a simple piece of javascript in google app script:

```
function doGet(e) {
  var outputJSON={};
  outputJSON['k']="m";
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(outputJSON))
  .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

This script when run gives the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot find function setMimeType in object {"k":"m"}.
```

This is a perfectly valid javascript. But yet the error occurs, likely due to `.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON)` as when I remove it, the code works.
So how to serve such dyamically created jsons from google script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
function doGet(){
  var outputJSON={};
  outputJSON['k']="m";
  var myJSON_toServe = ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(outputJSON));
  myJSON_toServe.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  return myJSON_toServe;  
}
```

It seems like it doesn't like returning the content and chaining methods at the same time.